# Synaptic says Samba installed, can't launch it

Tags: samba

Ubuntu & Lubuntu 12.04

I installed Samba with Synaptic Package Manager, but it doesn't show up on any of the Lubuntu menus. In Ubuntu it doesn't show either. Dash doesn't show it.

If I type "samba" into Terminal I get

```
The program 'samba' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install samba4
```

Yet Synaptic says that Samba is installed. I've logged out, and back in, and restarted the machine, still no sign of Samba. I'm not overlooking something obvious, am I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In easy simple words:

when you run samba in terminal then you  are calling the file serve window and if you are not installing before then you'll not find.

The packages you find in synaptic are part of these collections which are related to file sharing service that is founded by default in your system.

To be sure try to search for samba4 in synaptic which is the latest version of samba and you'll find that it's not installed.

Also notice that when you call samba in terminal thus you are running a command related to samba4. The other installed packages have different commands.

Comment: Thank you. I switched from the Ubuntu desktop to the Lubuntu desktop and installed samba from the Lubuntu Software Center and it installed and "samba" is now accessible from System Tools. I would like to mark this as "solved" but I cannot find the trick for that.